# Why cursor, opacity property and onclick event handler not work on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I want to create a portion in the image where when I click, it will alert hi. I know there are many ways to create portion on image, but I want it this way. The opacity property and the cursor property seems that does not work on IE9 because when I mouseOver the area it doesn't display pointer cursor and when I click on that portion it doesn't alert hi too. But that works fine on other browser. Can anybody explain why is this happening?

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");
  var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
  myDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  myDiv.style.width = "200px";
  myDiv.style.height = "200px";
  myDiv.style.top = "20px";
  myDiv.style.left = "20px";
  myDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  myDiv.style.cursor = "pointer";
  myDiv.style.border = "2px solid red";
  myDiv.style.opacity = 0.3;
  document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
  myDiv.onclick = function () {
    alert("hi");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="myImg" src="http://myartzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Gtelaviv_05.jpg">
```

Comment: I've eddited your post, and placed the code on the new Snippet Code feature (Ctrl + M). It looks ok!

Comment: Ya, it works with other browser, but not in ie9

Answer (score 0):

For cursor I must tell you that the only cross-browser syntax is:

```
element {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

There are some more information about the cursor as well:

> In the past the hand value was
>   Microsoft's way of saying pointer; and
>   IE 5.0 and 5.5 only support hand.
>   Because it's the cursor value that's
>   used most often, most other browsers
>   have also implemented hand.
>
> Since IE 6 and 7 support pointer,
>   there's no more reason to use hand,
>   except when older IEs are part of your
>   target audience.

For Opacity , IE 9 accepts

```
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
```

Check http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

For onClick event handler I think ,

> By default in IE9, Internet Options > Security Tab > Internet > Custom Level, scroll down to the Scripting section (near the bottom) and in Active Scripting is disabled, so put a check mark against Enable. And, this resolves the problem and the onclick works!!.

Comment: I think you have not read my answer properly ..i said IE 5 and 5.5 only supports hand ..after then hand was removed from the IE

Answer (score -1):

IE doesn't support pointer value for cursor property. You should use this:

```
myDiv.style.cursor='hand';
```

Opacity is value between 0 to 100 in IE. So set it like below:

```
myDiv.style.opacity=30;
```

After all I think you can use jquery to do these tasks very easily.

```
$('<div></div>').css({'cursor':'pointer', 'cursor':'hand', 'opacity':'30'}).click(function(){
    alert('hi');
})
```

Comment: Not true. IE supports `cursor: pointer` since version 6.0. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: i know its work but when executed on my works there isnt any effect?